# Neo4j import json data with different size of labels

Tags: json, shell, neo4j, cypher

I want import a json dataset in Neo4j using cypher-shell to create nodes. My json dataset is composed by a lot of attributes, and I don't know how much are them e which are their label. I write an example of my data:

```
{"business_id": "FYWN1wneV18bWNgQjJ2GNg","AcceptsInsurance": true, "ByAppointmentOnly": true, "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards": true},

{"business_id": "He-G7vWjzVUysIKrfNbPUQ","BusinessParking": {"garage": false, "street": false, "validated": false, "lot": true, "valet": false}, "HairSpecializesIn": {"coloring": true, "africanamerican": false, "curly": true, "perms": true, "kids": true, "extensions": true, "asian": true, "straightperms": true}, "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards": true, "RestaurantsPriceRange2": 3, "GoodForKids": true, "ByAppointmentOnly": false, "WheelchairAccessible": true},

{"business_id": "KQPW8lFf1y5BT2MxiSZ3QA"}
```

How Can I import this data in my db neo4j with Cypher-Shell? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: This phrase is not clear: "I don't know how much are them e which are their label". What exactly is your goal, and what exactly are the problems you are having?

Comment: The problem is that in this dataset there are different attributes, both in quantity and in form. It's very random structure. I mean, each JSON file aren't composed by static attributes, but it could be composed by array or static attributes, according to the single object. (Look at my example in my post and you will be able to understand the problem). So, I know how to import json object with static attributes, but I don't know how to manage json object with different kind of attributes.